# How to really switch off iAds when not required?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I'm building a paid app and an accompanying lite version with iAds. The paid version now and then displays this error in the log:

2011-09-12 15:05:24.751 [29318:12b03] ViewController::bannerView didFailToReceiveAdWithError (NO ADS):Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0x61d0b60 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}

I'm a bit surprised this happens, as I am doing this to stop iAds in the paid version:

```
[iAdBannerView removeFromSuperview];
iAdBannerView.hidden = YES;
// (not setting) iAdBannerView.delegate = nil; 
iAdBannerView = nil;
```

I cannot remove every reference to iAds in my app, as I have the iAd banner in a nib, and I prefer to have one nib with everything in it, for both app version. Hence the iAd framework *is* in my binary.

So, anyone an idea how to *really* stop the iAds system starting for your app when it should not?

Answer (score 0):

If you are to submit two separate apps to the AppStore, I would seriously consider creating a separate target for each on Xcode and user conditional compilation.

Something like this:

```
#ifdef FREE_VERSION

// Create iAd Banner

// add banner to superview

#endif // FREE_VERSION
```

That way, your paid version doesn't even have to link to the iAd framework nor you risk a a paid user seeing an ad because of a bug you introduce to the app.

Comment: That is what I do. But, the banner is in the nib. So, to be able to connect the ADBannerView to the world I need to tell the paid version a bit about iAds too. Alas, apparently having the iAds framework loaded also starts it up, causing the error in the log. Removing the iAds framework from the paid app target gives: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (ADBannerView)', so that doesn't work either.

Comment: In that case, I would either have separate nibs for the free and paid version, or remove it from the nib and add it with code on the free version only.

Comment: Exactly what I feared :-)  I like *everything* in the nib, adding things programmatically I think is messy. But, if messy pays the bills... I am not too proud for messy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use preprocessor commands to strip iAds from the paid version of your application.

In your prefix.pch you'd include something like this: `#define FREE_VERSION 1`

And then everywhere where you reference iAds, surround it with `#if FREE_VERSION` and `#endif`